# Git branch: branches not different

Tags: git, branch

For a few days, I have a problem with git.

Let's assume I have a branch "master". I create a branch "normal", I "git checkout normal", and then I change my code a bit.

If I "git checkout master", and then do a "git status", the changes I made on the branch normal are visible, while I'm on a completely different branch !

That's not the behavior I always had. I have to say I'm completely powerless right now. I don't know what happened.

Could you give me a hand ? I have git 2.3.3, and I'm on Manjaro Linux.

Comment: Did you commit your changes on _normal_ branch before checking _master_ out? Was `git checkout master` successful or did it report an error?

Comment: Nope, I did not commit my changes before I check master out. And yes, git checkout master was successful. And that's strange, because normally you can't checkout a branch if you didn't commit. I didn't have to 'git stash'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't commit your changes to *normal* branch. Only files in working directory were changed.

You can switch between Git branches even with changes in working directory. If there are no conflicts Git will show:

```
M       test.txt  
Switched to branch 'master'
```

This doesn't mean that those changes are now in *master* branch. They are simply in working directory. So you can now commit them to *master* (`git commit -a`) or check out *normal* and commit there.

If there is a conflict between your local changes and changes on branch you want to check out, Git will show an error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:  
         test.txt  
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.  
Aborting
```

In this case you need either to commit those changes, `stash` or completely discard in order to check out desired branch.

Comment: I didn"t know that, I thought the changes were in master too. Thanks.